# Chart.JS Chart top left corner is blocked by some visual nodejs

Tags: node.js, chart.js

i generated a bar graph with chart.JS but there is some weird thing at the top left corner,
see image: [image]

my CDN

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-d9xgZrVZpmmQlfonhQUvTR7lMPtO7NkZMkA0ABN3PHCbKA5nqylQ/yWlFAyY6hYgdF1Qh6nYiuADWwKB4C2WSw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

here is my code:

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
   
});</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working example of this, because with your code it just renders normally. So it must be something else in your code/page you didnt share. https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/nqt45jxw/

Comment: you were right, i had the canvas in a div, I took it out and that fixed it. @LeeLenalee

Answer (score 0):

fixed it,

i changed from

`<div> <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas></div>`

to

`<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>`